# Unable to Push docker image to AzureContainer Registry from Azure Devops

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-container-registry

Docker image has been created usefully

Successfully built 188e6513fb56
Successfully tagged satyam-hello:20210210.24

## My docker push Image task is not working

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: 'Push Container Image'
  inputs:
  containerRegistry: '$(SubscriptionEndpoint)'  #the ACR service connection created above
  repository: '$(acrHostName)'
  imageName: '$(imageName)'
  command: push
  tags: '$(tags)'
  ======
  below is the error

The push refers to repository [***.azurecr.io/***.azurecr.io]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: ***.azurecr.io/***.azurecr.io
##[error]An image does not exist locally with the tag: ***.azurecr.io/***.azurecr.io
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1

Comment: @ Did you get a chance to check out above update? How did it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `azureSubscriptionEndpoint` doesnot exist for Docker task. See [docker task document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops).

If you use Docker task to push your image to ACR. You need to create a [ACR service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-docreg).

Go to Project settings-->Service connection-->New Service connection-->Docker Registry -->Azure Container Registry/Others. See below screenshot.

[image]

As above error indicated, you also need to specify the `repository` property for the Docker task. See below example:

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: push
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: ACR-ServiceConnection  #the ACR service connection created above
    repository: MyRepository #the repository in your ACR
    command: push
```

Update:

There is no `imageName` parameter for docker task. If the image is `satyam-hello:20210210.24`. You should configure docker task as below:

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: push
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: ACR-ServiceConnection #$(SubscriptionEndpoint)
    repository: 'satyam-hello' #$(imageName)
    command: push
    tags: 20210210.24  #$(tags)
```

Comment: Do i need to perform docker login

Comment: @SatyamPandey No need to perform docker login.

Comment: @SatyamPandey And you can  [accept above answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it works out.

Comment: @ Levi Lu-MSFT No yet resolved i am getting below error, i have updated the taskThe push refers to repository [***.azurecr.io/***.azurecr.io]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: ***.azurecr.io/***.azurecr.io
##[error]An image does not exist locally with the tag: ***.azurecr.io/***.azurecr.io
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
Finishing: Push Container Image

Comment: @SatyamPandey You configured the docker task wrongly. Please check above to configure your docker task.